# Line number and java file name are missing in error log

Tags: java, ant, log4j

I have used ant build to build a .jar file. When i execute the jar, the line number and the java file name are missing in the log.

`[ERROR] [2013-05-07 07:26:26,900][abc.def.per#?] -common.exception.FatalException
        at abc.def.per.Ext(Unknown Source)`

The log4j patternlayout i used was 
`log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] [%d{ISO8601}][%c#%L] - %m%n`

If i execute the old jar which built earlier[some 3 yrs ago], i can see the proper log.
So i think no issues with the patternlayout. I hope the issue is in the build.
Please save me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using classes without debug information. You need to compile your classes using one of following commands.

```
javac -g
javac -g:lines,source
```

Debug information is added by default, so look for disabled debug or `-g:none` in your build scripts.

Comment: Am i doing right? In the build.xml, i have given like below. `<target name="compile_eg_delivery">
  <javac -g deprecation="off" srcdir="Source/build/ext_gen" destdir="Source/lib" debug="on" debuglevel="vars">
 </javac>
 </target> But getting the error as `Element type "javac" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

Comment: `<javac deprecation="off" srcdir="Source/build/ext_gen" destdir="Source/lib" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,vars,source"></javac>`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link: logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/… To me it seems you need to use %C or %F (caps) for displaying file name.